# Converting "2.800000000000000e+001" to ""28" in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, string, int

Here is XML received by any web service,

```
 <diy>
      <tag1>14</tag1>
      <tag2>2.000000000000000e+000</tag2>
      <tag3>2.800000000000000e+001</tag3>
 </diy>
```

This is code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xTag = from p in xmlDoc.Elements("document").Elements("xServ").Elements("b")
                                                 select p;
            string tab = "<Table>";


            foreach (var xTags in xTag)
            {
                tab += "<tr><td>" + Convert.ToString(xTags.Element("r").Element("Exp").Value) + "</td>";
                tab += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(xTags.Element("r").Element("diy").Element("tag1").Value) + "</td>";
                string s = Convert.ToString(xTags.Element("r").Element("diy").Element("tag2").Value);
                string d = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToString();
                tab += "<td>" + d + "</td>";
                tab += "<td>" + Convert.ToString(xTags.Element("r").Element("diy").Element("tag3").Value) + "</td>";
                tab += "</tr>";

            }
            divTag.InnerHtml = tab + "</Table>";
```

When I used Math.Round(), it gives me "2,8E+16" !

how can I convert "2.000000000000000e+000" to "2" and "2.800000000000000e+001" to "28" in ASP.NET ?

Comment: diy is class and tag1,tag2,tag3 are member? if member then which type i.e. float or ?. in web service class

Comment: @dash: Because of the exponent: 2.0*10^0 = 2, 2.8*10^1 = 28.

Comment: this is a part of xml document. i don't generated, i received by a web service

Comment: Will the result always be an integer, or could there be a float, too?

Comment: I use these in function, i.e. 14 * 2 = 28. so, they should be integer.

Comment: For each tag value, you can do  `Double.Parse("2.800000000000000e+001", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("N0");` to get the value `"28"` for example

Comment: Your question is answered in [Convert string to double with 2 digit after decimal separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588003/convert-string-to-double-with-2-digit-after-decimal-separator). Also you didn't explain what part you are having trouble with, reading the XML, converting a string to a floating point number, or rounding a number. Please try to use the search next time, and if you can't find an answer, explain exactly what you are doing and what you are having trouble with, and show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: @dash this return me 28.000.000.000.000.000 not 28

Comment: @dash How about my answer?

Comment: please show that what is in `s` ?

Comment: using System.Globalization;
    
    
    Double.Parse("2.800000000000000e+001", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("N0");

returns me 28.

thanks great @dash.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math` library:

```
Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("2.800000000000000e+001")).ToString();
```

that will return "28" .

Comment: If I run your code, I get the value "28.0" - i.e. the output is a double - you still need to format it to remove the decimal places.

Comment: @dash `Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("2.800000000000000e+001")).ToString();`!

Comment: That returns `"28"` for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
decimal.Parse("2.800000000000000e+001", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float).ToString("0.#");
```

Edit: added .NET format string to reduce to "28"

Comment: this return 28.0000000000000 !

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int function(float tag2)
{
 do
 {
  if(tag2%10==0)
  {
   tag2=tag2/10.0;
  }
  else
  {
   int res = tag2;
   return res;
  }
 }
 while(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well I have to say that my solution is a bit funny! and beside that uses more memory than other ways.although other solutions use more cpu! life is trade off!

```
        string MyNumber = "2.8000000e+1";
        int DotIndex = MyNumber.IndexOf('.');
        MyNumber = MyNumber.Remove(DotIndex, 1);
        if(MyNumber[DotIndex] != '0')
          DotIndex++;
        MyNumber = MyNumber.Remove(DotIndex, MyNumber.Length - DotIndex);
        DotIndex = Int32.Parse(MyNumber);
        //MessageBox.Show(MyNumber); just to show the result!
```

It will return "2" for an input like "2.00000000e+1" AND "28" for "2.8000000e+1"!